# Can not compile @import after preprocessing

Tags: objective-c, llvm-clang

I am preprocessing code with clang before compiling it and with modules enabled clang converts "#import <float.h>" to "@import Darwin.C.float;". When I try to compile this preprocessed source, I get the following error: "Expected a module name after module import" because "float" is a reserved word. Is there a way to disable the checking of reserved words in @import?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the same thing. You can probably hack around it with:

```
@import Darwin.C;
```

**Update**
I found an [open LLVM bug](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=19557) about this.